# Open to new window or tab on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make different countries in this map (http://jsfiddle.net/hansenmc/EnqP3/) open to a new tab or window. I am able to open in the same window without an issue using this code.

```
     onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
        
        
        if(code == 'il'){
window.open("www.mywebsite.com", "_blank");
}
```

When I use this code it opens in the same window and a new window simultaneously.

```
    onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
        
        
        if(code == 'us'){
window.open = "www.mywebsite.com, _blank";
}
```

Any help getting different countries to open into their own window would be greatly appreciated. I have tried solutions from other threads but none seem to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` is a function, so it should be called instead of assigned to.

Instead of:

```
window.open = "www.mywebsite.com, _blank";
```

It should be:

```
window.open("www.mywebsite.com", "_blank");
```

Also, if you want the function open the URL correctly, it should include the `http(s)://` prefix, otherwise it will open a relative path from the current windows location in some browsers.

The full code in your case would be:

```
onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
    if(code == 'us'){
        window.open("www.mywebsite.com", "_blank");
    }
}
```

Shorter version:

```
onRegionClick(element, code, region) => {
    if(code == 'us')
        window.open("www.mywebsite.com", "_blank");
}
```

For a dynamic URL, something like the following would work:

```
onRegionClick(element, code, region) => {
    if(code == 'us')
        window.open(`www.mywebsite.com/${code}`, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: I do not doubt you are correct. I just cannot make it work. It still opens the page in the same window and a new window.

Comment: I've just had another look at the fiddle and it's not this particular code that's causing the problem and it seems there's a lot more issues to worry about with that Fiddle other than the page opening twice. You seem to have 2 listeners for each element, which is causing the code provided here twice. This code functions correctly so the bug is elsewhere. Could you debug the script and post the part of the code that is actually causing the problem? It will more than likely be the part that adds the event listeners to the elements themselves.

Comment: There's no code in that Fiddle that has `window.open` or even just `window` on it's own.

Comment: I've just put that code into your Fiddle and tested it myself and it does open the page in a new tab AND keeps the JS Fiddle tab open and on the same page. I inserted `window.open("https://stackoverflow.com", "_blank")` on line 109 of your fiddle and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've even put it in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pvwcra0d/1/

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have no experience with this. Your solution works and now each country opens to Google. I am trying to make each country open to a unique page. I will try to tweak your suggestions to do that.

Comment: I've added an example of a dynamic URL to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Event object `.preventDefault()` method on `windown.open()`.